# Get weekofweekyear in NodaTime asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, nodatime

```
public static int IsoWeekOfYear(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            var date = new LocalDate(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);
            //weekOfWeekYear
            return date.WeekOfWeekYear;
        }
```

WeekOfWeekYear does not exist in the LocalDate Assembly..

How an I go around this?

Comment: What version of NodaTime are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET Core, you're *probably* using a beta of 2.0. (I'm hoping to release 2.0 within a week.)

The week-of-week-year handling has been overhauled for 2.0. In 2.0 you'd use:

```
return WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date);
```

(You'll need a `using` directive for the `NodaTime.Calendars` namespace.)

If you want to use a non-ISO week numbering, you can use one of the factory methods in `WeekYearRules`.

Comment: Thanks, both the options helped!